# please help me understand why rider isn't being recognized in this kotlin code

Tags: android-studio, kotlin

this is the XML which seems okay

```
<Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/iam_a_rider"
        android:id= "@+id/rider"/>
//this the XML code for the button I created that I would like to declare in the main activity page
```

this is the code I was trying to execute but was not successful since it keeps bring an error of val not recognised with in the code

main activity kt

```
 class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity()
{
     override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

         val rider: Button = findViewById<Button>(R.id.rider)
        
         rider.setOnClickListener()
      
// still brings an error of rider not in use or doesn't recognise it at all
        }
```

Comment: Hey, this code works for me, the only thing I've changed is `rider.setOnClickListener { }`.

Can you provide your full code for `activity_main.xml` and `MainActivity.kt`?

Comment: Please include the actual line of code that has an error and tell us exactly what the error is.